# Site with 1M pageviews/day with RubyOnRails... Unicorn or Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, scalability

I have a site developed using RubyOnRails framework... I'll format my server and which is better? Unicorn or Passenger?

Comment: I tagged this as off topic as you would get a much better answer from a systems/server administrator, but before they could even begin to give you a recommendation, you might want to provide more information about the research that you've done up to this point.

Comment: I think you have been precipitated. @Godsaur gave a great response, and I read a nice blog post on GitHub about Unicorn. They helped me find the best tool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both have their usages.

Unicorn is good for fast clients, however it's not great with slow ones.

Passenger is a proven technology, it's proven well with high traffic applications.

Comment: I'd personally use passenger in your case.  Unicorn is a new kid on the block and you need something that well proven given your load.

Comment: Thanks, is very useful for me I'm still studying. :D